# Marionette.js Layout Only Render Single Element of template

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, marionette

I got some issues with marionette.js and have spending some hours to look at error source but I cannot find it, my layout not render its templates correctly, it is only render element inside the first div of the template.

here is the actual template, headerlayout.html:

```
   <div class="header-logo-bg relative" id="header_logo">
        <a href="/" title="Apps Title">
            <div class="logo"></div>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div id="home_btn">
        <a href="/">
            <div class="back_to_all_modules">
                Back to<br>
                All Modules
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>


    <div class="header_menu" id="header_menu">

    </div>
```

but the rendered result is only like this:

```
<div>
<a href="/" title="Apps Title">
    <div class="logo"></div>
</a>
```

here is my Backbone layout:

```
define([
    'marionette',
    'modules/header/views/menulayout',
    'tpl!modules/header/templates/headerlayout.html'
], function (Marionette, MenuLayout, layoutTemplate) {


    var HeaderLayout = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({
        template: layoutTemplate,

        regions: {
            menuRegion: '#header_menu'
        },
        initialize: function () {
            console.log('initializing header layout');
        },
        onRender: function () {
            console.log('onRender headerlayout');
            var menuLayout = new MenuLayout();
            this.menuRegion.show(menuLayout);
        }
    });

    return HeaderLayout;
});
```

And here is my header layout called from the backbone application:

```
define([
    'marionette',
    'modules/header/views/headerlayout'
], function (Marionette, HeaderLayout) {

    // set up the app instance
    var myApp = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();

    // configuration, setting up regions, etc ...
    myApp.addRegions({
        header: '#header',
        content: '#content',
        footer: '#footer',
        dialog: '#dialog'
    });

    myApp.addInitializer(function () {
        var headerLayout = new HeaderLayout();
        myApp.header.show(headerLayout);
    });

    // export the app from this module
    return myApp;
});
```

do I miss something here? any help would be appreciated, thanks. And sorry for my poor english.

Comment: I don't see any problem with your code, maybe it's something wrong within your template, a strange character encoding maybe?

Comment: @Ingro yes, you are right, nothing wrong with the code, the error source lay on requirejs config file.

Comment: We have exactly the same problem.... what is the fix?

Answer (score 0):

In your layout, try repalcing the `onRender` function with `onShow`.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh hah.

have worked it out.

Marionette is expecting a template object, not a text template. And for what ever reason you are giving it a piece of text not an object. Yes your code should work.. but we ahave the same problem and are not using the tpl! functionality we are using text!

this will work:

```
define(['underscore'
    'marionette',
    'modules/header/views/menulayout',
    'text!modules/header/templates/headerlayout.html'
], function (_,Marionette, MenuLayout, layoutTemplate) {


    var HeaderLayout = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({
        template: _.template(layoutTemplate),
```